# Are Kohanim of a mishmar REQUIRED to work, or can they opt not to?

Tags: kodshim, kohen-priest

Background: Mishna Yevamos 100. The mishna discusses a Kohen of uncertain lineage citing an example of someone who may be the son of two different men, both of whom are Kohanim. We KNOW for certain then that this individual is a Kohen, but we don't know which mishmar they are part of.
In this case the person of uncertain parentage will work for two mishmaros but they do not get any of the kodshim because the members of each mishmar will say they are not really entitled because hamotzy mechaveiro alav ha'raya.

Question:  Essentially this takes a month out of a person's year for the avodah, but there is no financial support for this time worked. Well and good if the kohen is wealthy. But if they are not, and they have a chiyuv to work this could be difficult. Or perhaps, the avodah is not a chiyuv on the individual but a reshus for them. In which case, the Kohen in question could work if he is able to, but if he is not able to support himself he is not required to.

Comment: Is your question if he’s mechuyiv to work or how he can afford it? If you look at the Gemara on that Mishnah on 101A it says that the mishmar itself can force him to work because of pgam Mishpacha. It’s also mashma like that in the Mishnah itself. As far as support, that’s why they get 24 matnos kehuna

Comment: My question is more how he could be mechuyav to work if he is not cholek. He has to work for 2 mishmaros which = a month out of the year but he does not get any of the benefits because each mishmar will say he is not entitled to any

Comment: There Gemara clearly states that he can be forced to work. He still has a way to get teruma etc

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Shmuel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3):

The Gemara on this Mishna, in Yevamos 101A clearly states that the wording of the Mishnah is meant to imply that he can be forced to serve both weeks in the Bais Hamikdash.

> וְעוֹלֶה בְּמִשְׁמָרוֹ וְכוּ׳. וְכִי מֵאַחַר דְּאֵינוֹ חוֹלֵק, לָמָּה עוֹלֶה? לָמָּה עוֹלֶה?! הָאָמַר: בָּעֵינָא דְּנֶיעְבֵּיד מִצְוָה! אֶלָּא: ״עָלָה״ לָא קָתָנֵי, אֶלָּא ״עוֹלֶה״ — בְּעַל כׇּרְחוֹ.

> It is stated in the mishna: And he ascends to the Temple service with the priestly watch of both uncertain fathers. However, he does not receive a share of the offerings of either watch. The Gemara asks: Since he does not receive a share, why does he ascend? The Gemara is puzzled by this question: Why does he ascend? Doesn’t he naturally say: I wish to perform a mitzva by serving as a priest? The Gemara explains: However, note that the mishna does not state: If he ascended, but rather: He ascends, in the present tense. Apparently he is obligated to ascend, even against his will.

The [Ritv”a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Yevamot.101a.1?lang=bi) on this explains that the non participation in the matanos is a reason not to work:

> ולהכי מתמיהי' היאך כופי' אותו לעלות משום מצוה **הואיל ואינו חולק** ואין ידוע משמרו

I found in the Mosad Rav Kook Ritv”a in footnote 352 on this piece, (these footnotes were written by R  Avraham Yaffin) that he explains that the Ritv”a means to address your exact question! He says, since we know that the matanos of a korban are “in lieu of your work” (words of the passuk) so since he doesn’t get the matanos he shouldn’t work. According to the Ritv”a, the Gemara is answering, that nonetheless he still has to work to avoid family shame, regardless of how he makes it happen.